# Codeigniter isset() with or condition not working in multiple parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

```
$viewdata['branch']= $this->input->post('branch'); 
if (isset($viewdata['branch']) || isset($viewdata['address']) || isset($viewdata['timings']) || isset($viewdata['clinic']) || isset($viewdata['latitude']) || isset($viewdata['longitude']) || isset($viewdata['image'])) {
    //print_r($viewdata);exit;
    $logid = $this->Adminmodel->Insertdata("table", $viewdata);
}
```

Why `isset()` condition is not working with `Or`. It is directly inserting into table. What should I do?

Comment: are you trying to insert data if you find any one of $viewdata to be true, or you need all of the $viewdata indexes to be true?

Comment: any one of $viewdata to be true

Comment: For eg branch and address are given then it should be insert into table_log

Comment: may isset will be true even if value is empty, so you can try like this if(isset($viewdata['branch']) && $viewdata['branch']!=""  || so on....)

Comment: Can you show from where $viewdata['address'], $viewdata['timings'],..... etc are coming from?

Comment: no same results all are inserting when if the value is empty @Daman Mokha

Comment: `not empty` is not the same as `isset`. The latter means there is a variable with that name, though it may not have been assigned any value, or it may be a string of length 0, NULL, ... If `$var = '';` then `isset($var)` is true but `empty($var)` is also true. Try doing something like `if ( (isset($var1) && !empty($var1)) || (isset($var2) && !empty($var2)) || ... )`

Comment: Then please add the source of $viewdata where it is coming from.

Comment: haha same result yaar  see im passing 2 variable for eg $['data']=$this->input->post('hi'); and another as $viewdata['branch']=$this->input->post('branch');like so on.. . for $data im update the tables where as $viewdata im inserting into another log table

Comment: before inserting im updating the value first . So isset value in not empty that is reason why value is coming . Hmm  i have check with alternative way. Any way thanks :) - Daman Mokha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php, `$something = isset($_POST['something']) ? $_POST['something'] : NULL;`
With CodeIgniter’s built in methods you can simply do this: `$something = $this->input->post('something');`

```
// Example
$input = $this->input->post('input_name');
```

`$input` will be `input_name's value` if `input_name's value` is set.

`$input` will be `NULL` if `input_name's value` is set.

So when you checking `isset()` again on `$input`. Definately, the value is set and it is null.

Reference
[Codeigniter Input Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

Comment: yes i have tested working fine . Thanks q @SoeChit kaung

Comment: i wrote this condition  isset($viewdata['branch_name']) && !empty($viewdata['branch_name']) ||